# Problem with FindOne using mongo-driver/mongo in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mongo-go

Struggling with unmarshalling data in Golang from mongo, may be cause I am new to this. Just started learning golang with MongoDB

Tried with map[string]interface{} to avoid any struct related errors

```
var data map[string]interface{}
filter := bson.M{"profile.username": username}
singleResult := u.getCollection(client).FindOne(u.ctx, filter)
err := singleResult.Decode(data)
```

This fails to unmarshall with error **cannot Decode to nil value**

Tried with exact struct structure too.

```
var result *models.UserData
filter := bson.M{"profile.username": username}
singleResult := u.getCollection(client).FindOne(u.ctx, filter)
err := singleResult.Decode(result)
```

Fails with same error **cannot Decode to nil value**

Tried to find all with map[string]interface{}

```
var result []models.UserData
cursor, _ := u.getCollection(client).Find(u.ctx, bson.M{})
err := cursor.All(u.ctx, &result)
```

Works perfectly as expected

Tried to find all with exact struct structure

```
var data []map[string]interface{}
cursor, _ := u.getCollection(client).Find(u.ctx, bson.M{})
err := cursor.All(u.ctx, &result)
```

Works perfectly as expected

Now I thought may be I am not finding the data in mongo but then

```
filter := bson.M{"profile.username": username}
singleResult := u.getCollection(client).FindOne(u.ctx, filter)
raw, _ := singleResult.DecodeBytes()
log.Print("\n\n" + raw.String()+"\n\n")
```

This prints the data as expected. Although one thing I noticed all non-string values are formatted as `{"$numberLong":"1"}`. Still don't know if it is correct or cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `Decode()` to write the document(s) into the passed value, it must be a (non-`nil`) pointer. Passing any value creates a copy, and if you pass a non-pointer, only the copy could be modified. If you pass a pointer, a copy is still made, but `Decode()` will modify the *pointed* value, not the pointer.

In your first 2 examples that fail, you pass a non-pointer (or a `nil` pointer):

```
err := singleResult.Decode(result)
```

Modify it to pass a (non-`nil`) pointer:

```
err := singleResult.Decode(&result)
```

Your last 2 examples work because you're already passing (non-`nil`) pointers:

```
err := cursor.All(u.ctx, &result)
```

Comment: In the second example that fail, a pointer named `result` is already passed: `var result *models.UserData ... err := singleResult.Decode(result)`.

Comment: The passed value is of pointer type, true, but it's `nil`, so `Decode()` can't modify the _pointed_ value because it points to nowhere. You must pass a non-`nil` pointer value.

Comment: Yes, I mean your answer does not indicate `nil` pointer, "In your first 2 examples that fail, you pass a non-pointer: ... Modify it to pass a pointer". I think the `nil` pointer is the main reason leading to the `Decode()` error in question.

Comment: @rustyhu Included the point about non-`nil` pointers. Codes included in the answer work without modification.

Answer (score 0):

In your first 2 examples that fail, the data passed to `Decode()` are both `nil`:

```golang
// data == nil
var data map[string]interface{}
// ...

// result == nil
var result *models.UserData
```

Try like

```golang
var result = &models.UserData{} // init the pointer with a block of valid allocated memory
// ...
err := singleResult.Decode(result)
```